# Unique string combinations

Tags: r, vector, unique, combinations

I have a vector which contains certain words

```
colors<-c("Yellow","Blue","Red")

> colors
[1] "Yellow" "Blue"   "Red"
```

Now I want to create a new variable, *colorsCombined*, in which the original vector is present and also all possible combinations of those words.

```
> colorsCombined
[1] "Yellow", "Blue", "Red", "YellowBlue", "YellowRed", "BlueRed", "YellowBlueRed"
```

I consider YellowBlue to be the same as BlueYellow.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option is to run the `combn` function in a `lapply` loop. You can define it as your own function

```
allCombs <- function(x) c(x, lapply(seq_along(x)[-1L], 
                             function(y) combn(x, y, paste0, collapse = "")),
                             recursive = TRUE)

allCombs(colors)
## [1] "Yellow" "Blue" "Red" "YellowBlue" "YellowRed" "BlueRed" "YellowBlueRed"
```

**Explanation** (per request)

Basically OP wants a vector of all possible combinations (*not* permutations) depending on the length of the input vector. Thus, we should run the `combn` function over `k <- 1:length(x)` and generate all combinations for every `k`.
So when `k == 1`, it's just the original vector, so we can skip that part and just concatenate the original vector using `c`. The rest of the generated combinations return a list of vectors with different lengths (in a descending order for obvious reasons), thus we need to use `recursive = TRUE` within the `c` function in order to mimic the behaviour of `unlist` and combine the results into a single vector.