# Generate chronological sequence

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector `c("m1","m2","m3","m4")`

I need to generate all kinds of chronological sequence possible.
The output for the above should look like

```
c("m1","m1 m2","m1 m2 m3","m1 m2 m3 m4","m2","m2 m3","m2 m3 m4","m3","m3 m4","m4")
```

I would like the code to avoid any loop since I need to run it for a large data.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29387475/unique-string-combinations/29387640#29387640) helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `combn` with the indicated function, include the singletons and sort:

```
Paste <- function(x) paste(m[x[1]:x[2]], collapse = " ")
sort(c(m, combn(length(m), 2, FUN = Paste)))
```

giving:

```
[1] "m1"          "m1 m2"       "m1 m2 m3"    "m1 m2 m3 m4" "m2"         
[6] "m2 m3"       "m2 m3 m4"    "m3"          "m3 m4"       "m4"
```

If the order does not matter omit `sort`.

**Note:** If we preferred a list of character vectors (rather than a vector of pasted character strings) then this slightly simpler code would provide it unsorted:

```
enlist <- function(x) list(m[x[1]:x[2]])
L <- c(m, combn(length(m), 2, FUN = enlist))
```

giving:

```
> str(L)
List of 10
 $ : chr "m1"
 $ : chr "m2"
 $ : chr "m3"
 $ : chr "m4"
 $ : chr [1:2] "m1" "m2"
 $ : chr [1:3] "m1" "m2" "m3"
 $ : chr [1:4] "m1" "m2" "m3" "m4"
 $ : chr [1:2] "m2" "m3"
 $ : chr [1:3] "m2" "m3" "m4"
 $ : chr [1:2] "m3" "m4"
```

Comment: That's quite clever way of avoiding a loop. Very nice answer.