# Loop for different combination of string

Tags: r, loops

I have a list of string s below

```
for_vector <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j")
```

I want to generate a loop that will print all possible combinations of the strings above. The combination of stings should be by 1 up to 10 just like below

```
a
b
c
.
.
j
.
.
a+b
a+c
.
.
a+b+c....+j
```

Comment: Have a look at function `combn`.

Comment: Is this useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29387475/unique-string-combinations/ ?

Comment: You can also try with an `expand.grid` solution

Comment: @DavidArenburg Looks like a completer duplicate for me.