# Unique string combinations of consecutive integers

Tags: r, vector, combinations

I have a vector of integers from 0-9 and need all unique possible combinations of these consecutive vector elements, including the original elements.

```
> vec <- 0:9
> vec
 [1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

The task is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29387475/unique-string-combinations). The major (and tricky) difference is that I only need consecutive combinations (e.g `"0", "01", "012", ... "0123456789", ... "1", ... "123456789"`) and not non-consecutive combinations (such as `"013"`).

How would I go about creating this subset of combinations?

Comment: What is a "non-continuous combination"?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, meant consecutive (will edit post). Combinations of consecutive integers. 0 and 1 are consecutive, 0 and 2 are not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a nested `sapply` approach

```
unlist(
  sapply(
    seq_along(vec),
    function(k) {
      sapply(
        k:length(vec),
        function(l) paste0(vec[k:l], collapse = "")
      )
    }
  )
)
```

which produces

```
 [1] "0"          "01"         "012"        "0123"       "01234"     
 [6] "012345"     "0123456"    "01234567"   "012345678"  "0123456789"
[11] "1"          "12"         "123"        "1234"       "12345"
[16] "123456"     "1234567"    "12345678"   "123456789"  "2"
[21] "23"         "234"        "2345"       "23456"      "234567"
[26] "2345678"    "23456789"   "3"          "34"         "345"
[31] "3456"       "34567"      "345678"     "3456789"    "4"
[36] "45"         "456"        "4567"       "45678"      "456789"
[41] "5"          "56"         "567"        "5678"       "56789"
[46] "6"          "67"         "678"        "6789"       "7"
[51] "78"         "789"        "8"          "89"         "9"
```

---

Another option is `sapply` + `embed`

```
unlist(
  sapply(
    seq_along(vec),
    function(k) {
      do.call(paste0, rev(data.frame(embed(vec, k))))
    }
  )
)
```

which gives

```
 [1] "0"          "1"          "2"          "3"          "4"
 [6] "5"          "6"          "7"          "8"          "9"
[11] "01"         "12"         "23"         "34"         "45"
[16] "56"         "67"         "78"         "89"         "012"
[21] "123"        "234"        "345"        "456"        "567"
[26] "678"        "789"        "0123"       "1234"       "2345"
[31] "3456"       "4567"       "5678"       "6789"       "01234"
[36] "12345"      "23456"      "34567"      "45678"      "56789"
[41] "012345"     "123456"     "234567"     "345678"     "456789"
[46] "0123456"    "1234567"    "2345678"    "3456789"    "01234567"
[51] "12345678"   "23456789"   "012345678"  "123456789"  "0123456789"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the `embed` version!!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a one-liner with `RcppAlgos` (I am the author):

```
RcppAlgos::comboGeneral(10, 2, repetition = TRUE, FUN = function(r) {
    paste((0:9)[r[1]:r[2]], collapse = "")
}, FUN.VALUE = "a")
 [1] "0"          "01"         "012"        "0123"       "01234"      "012345"    
 [7] "0123456"    "01234567"   "012345678"  "0123456789" "1"          "12"        
[13] "123"        "1234"       "12345"      "123456"     "1234567"    "12345678"  
[19] "123456789"  "2"          "23"         "234"        "2345"       "23456"     
[25] "234567"     "2345678"    "23456789"   "3"          "34"         "345"       
[31] "3456"       "34567"      "345678"     "3456789"    "4"          "45"        
[37] "456"        "4567"       "45678"      "456789"     "5"          "56"        
[43] "567"        "5678"       "56789"      "6"          "67"         "678"       
[49] "6789"       "7"          "78"         "789"        "8"          "89"        
[55] "9"
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution, based on `purrr::map`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

map(0:9, \(x) map(x:9, \(y) str_c(x:y, collapse = ""))) %>% unlist

#>  [1] "0"          "01"         "012"        "0123"       "01234"     
#>  [6] "012345"     "0123456"    "01234567"   "012345678"  "0123456789"
#> [11] "1"          "12"         "123"        "1234"       "12345"     
#> [16] "123456"     "1234567"    "12345678"   "123456789"  "2"         
#> [21] "23"         "234"        "2345"       "23456"      "234567"    
#> [26] "2345678"    "23456789"   "3"          "34"         "345"       
#> [31] "3456"       "34567"      "345678"     "3456789"    "4"         
#> [36] "45"         "456"        "4567"       "45678"      "456789"    
#> [41] "5"          "56"         "567"        "5678"       "56789"     
#> [46] "6"          "67"         "678"        "6789"       "7"         
#> [51] "78"         "789"        "8"          "89"         "9"
```